# Increase column's size in Oracle DB tables with Knex.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, size, knex.js

I have a Password's column in a table, stored in OracleDB 11g.

In order to store hashed passwords on it, I need to increment its size from 25 to 60 or 100 BYTE.

I do not want to do this manually, I hope I can find a script or anything else using KnexJS (Something like migrations or seeds)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know. But, why wouldn't you simply `alter table your_table modify password_column varchar2(100 byte)`?

Comment: I dont know, I want use this knex.schema.raw('alter table MYTABLE modify MYCOLUMN varchar2(100)'). Is it going to work?

Comment: No idea, sorry, as I don't know node.js and "knex.schema.raw" is something I never saw before. But, as of **Oracle** itself, such a command would work.

Comment: Why do you "want use this knex.schema.raw"? Why are you so wedded to the idea of using some framework just to issue a simple, single, one-time SQL statement, as was suggested by @Littlefoot

Comment: I'm working in a project using Node.js, Knex.js and Oracle Db, so basically I want to create a migration file in order to ser size 255 after runing the app. I don"t know if there is another idea.

Answer (score 6):

The correct term for what you want to do is "increase", not "increment". It looks like Knex.js supports changing the default DDL for columns (which is to create) to alter via the `alter` method. http://knexjs.org/#Schema-alter

In theory, it should work something like this:

```
knex.schema.alterTable('user', function(t) {
  t.string('password', 100).alter();
});
```

I must admit, the following verbage in this method has me a little concerned:

> Alter is not done incrementally over older column type so if you like to add notNull and keep the old default value, the alter statement must contain both .notNull().defaultTo(1).alter().

I'm not sure what that means at the end of the day. Just be sure to test this in development before trying it in production!

Comment: It means that if you have created not nullable column without default `t.string(...).notNull()` then doing `t.string(...)..defaultTo('foo').alter()` will change it to be nullable with default value 'foo'. So altering doesn't work incrementally, but it overrides the whole old column declaration (I'm not sure if this explanation was at all more clear than the one from docs).

Comment: Not quite clear. In Oracle Database, if I create a table with `create table t (c varchar2(30) not null)` and later alter the column with `alter table t modify c varchar2(100)`, the not null constraint isn't lost. So what is Knex.js doing that causes it to be lost?

Comment: With postgresql it first drops all constraints / default values and then changes column type and lastly add newly declared contraints and defaults. With mysql it uses also `alter table modify ...` which as far as I know also does complete redeclaration of column including, so old `not null` and `default value` are implicitly dropped. However it might be that actually with oracle it works differently and there is a bug in knex and correctly generated alter would be something like `alter table t modify c varchar2(100) null default NULL` to drop null and "remove" default.